# C problem involving Arrays and garbage characters likely a memory problem

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers

Trying to sort an array of strings. Both the strings themselves and the strings in the array. Code seems to sort the strings themselves fine but after calling the sortList function I just get garbage characters. First time messing around with pointers and C.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 11
#define LEN 20
void sortList(char* ptr[], int size);
void sortChars(char *str);
void swap(char *a[], int c, int b);


int main()
{
    char *list[LEN];
    int i, n;
    char input[SIZE+2];

    printf("How many strings will you enter");
    scanf("%d", &n );
    getchar();

    //start reading strings
    if(n<=LEN)
    {
        for(i = 0; i< n;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter string %d: ",i+1);
            fgets(input, SIZE +2, stdin);
            input[strcspn(input,"\n")] = '\0';
            list[i] = strdup(input);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
        printf("item %d is %s\n", i+1 ,list[i]);

    for(i = 0; i<n;i++)
    {
        sortChars(list[i]);
        printf("item %d is %s\n",i+1, list[i]);
    }

    sortList(list, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
        free(list[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < n ;i++)
        printf("item %d is %s\n", i+1, list[i]);

    return 0;
}

void sortChars(char *str)
{
    int i,j;
    int len = strlen(str);
    for(i = 0; i< len -1;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ;j<len-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(str[j]>str[j+1])
            {
                char tem = str[j];
                str[j] = str[j+1];
                str[j+1]= tem;
            }
        }
    }
}

void sortList(char *ptr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(ptr[i], ptr[i+1]) > 0)
             swap(ptr,i,i+1);
    }
}

void swap(char *ptra[], int a, int b)
{
    char *temp = ptra[a];
    ptra[a] = ptra[b];
    ptra[b]= temp;
}
```

Code should sort the strings. Then sort the order of the strings in the list.

Here is a sample of what I am getting:

```
Enter string 1: hello

Enter string 2: world

item 1 is hello

item 2 is world

item 1 is ehllo

item 2 is dlorw

item 1 is =

item 2 is ▒▒3
```

Comment: Show all of your code including ```#include <stdio.h>```,  ```#include <stdlib.h>```,  ```#define LEN ??```, and ```#define SIZE ??```.

Answer (score 0):

> after calling the sortList function I just get garbage characters.

Okay, let's look at that code...

```
sortList(list, n);

for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    free(list[i]);                            // <-- You free list[i]

for(i = 0; i < n ;i++)
    printf("item %d is %s\n", i+1, list[i]);  // <-- You try to use list[i]
```

The first thing to notice is that you `free` all items in `list` prior to printing them out. This is undefined behavior. After you free memory, you must not use that memory -- it no longer belongs to you.

So, the first fix is to swap the order of those. Don't `free` until you're *actually* finished with that memory:

```
sortList(list, n);

for(i = 0; i < n ;i++)
    printf("item %d is %s\n", i+1, list[i]);

for(i = 0; i < n;i++)
    free(list[i]);
```

The second issue is that your program *still* has undefined behavior because of the `sortList` function. Let's take a look at it:

```
void sortList(char *ptr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(ptr[i], ptr[i+1]) > 0)      // <-- ptr[i+1] can overflow
             swap(ptr,i,i+1);
    }
}
```

Although this *looks* reasonable to the beginner's eye, it's actually broken. The problem is that you loop `size` times, but inside the loop, you're using both `i` and `i+1` to compare the "current" and "next" values. But that means on the last iteration, `i+1` is going to reference a value that you never initialized. The fix is to do exactly what you did in your `sortChars` function, and iterate over one less item:

```
void sortList(char *ptr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(ptr[i], ptr[i+1]) > 0)
             swap(ptr,i,i+1);
    }
}
```

But you're not done! This only makes one pass for sorting, and is only going to work properly for 2 values. You already know how to sort more than that, as you're doing this in `sortChars`. So that can be left as an exercise for you.